# How to mock a decorator function used on method that is used in SUT in JEST

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs

I have a typescript class:

```
export class SystemUnderTest {

  @LogThisAction('sth was done')
  public doSomething() {} 

}
```

As you can see it uses a reflection to execute some decoration function:

```
 export declare function LogThisAction(action: string): (target: any) => 
 void;
```

When I run test in I do not care about the actual impl. of this decorator function, so I try to mock it like this:

```
 myModule = require(./DecoratorFunctions);
 myModule.LogThisAction = jest.fn();
```

But that does not seem to work. When I run tests I get:

```
● Test suite failed to run
TypeError: decorator is not a function
at DecorateProperty (node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js:553:33)
```

How to achieve my goal in JEST framework ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your decorator is technically a function which is **returning** another function.

So your mock is not correct and it should return a function, try it with:

```
myModule = require(./DecoratorFunctions);
myModule.LogThisAction = () => jest.fn();
```

Comment: Does not works with import pattern when you use import in TypeScript :(

Answer (score 2):

You can use the

> jest.mock

to mock the module and the underlying implementation

```
jest.mock('./DecoratorFunctions', () => ({ LogThisAction: (item: any) => {
return (target, propertyKey, descriptor) => {
  // save a reference to the original method
  const originalMethod = descriptor.value as () => Promise<any>;
  descriptor.value = async function(...args) {
    originalMethod.apply(this, args);
    return response;
  };

  return descriptor;
}; }}));
```

This will mock the implementation of **LogThisAction**